# Add_query_arg + two times the same argument?

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, multi-taxonomy-query

I'am trying to filter my archive page by clicking links. When clicked they execute the add_query_arg command.

Everything works fine so far.

But now i want to add combinations within the same custom taxonomy.

ex: http://url.com/archive/ '?events=test&events=test2'

now the question, how to add two times the same argument with add_query_arg without overwriting the first one ? And how to get them again ?

Hope someone can help me out here.

Best regards

Comment: You can pass two values as comma separated in a single parameter `events`. And later parse value correctly in your page.

Comment: that sounds good ! i'm going to try that. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nilambar's comment solved this for me.

> "You can pass two values as comma separated in a single parameter
>   events. And later parse value correctly in your page. –  Nilambar"

I use this to get posts with tag1 OR tag2:

```
echo '<a href="'.esc_attr(add_query_arg( 'events', 'tag1,tag2')).'">Linkname</a>';
```

And to get all posts with tag1 AND tag2 simply use "+" instead of ",":

```
echo '<a href="'.esc_attr(add_query_arg( 'events', 'tag1+tag2')).'">Linkname</a>';
```

Thanks Nilambar !

Comment: Glad that I could be of some help :-)