# WP_query taxonomy + get all posts with two terms from same taxonomy

Tags: wp-query, advanced-taxonomy-queries

This is a follow up question to [Add_query_arg + two times the same argument?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/157632/add-query-arg-two-times-the-same-argument)

I want to get the post count from all posts tagged with 2 different tags from same taxonomy

```
$args2 = array(
    'post_type' => 'custom',
    'tax_query' => array( 'relation' => 'AND' )
);
$args['tax_query'][0] = array( 
    'taxonomy' => 'events',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => 'tag1' 
);
$args['tax_query'][1] = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'events',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => 'tag-2' 
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
echo $query->post_count;
```

With this code I only get the post_count for one of these tags. How i do get both?
I couldn't find an answer at Wordpress codex.

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to 2 array for tax query. You can try this scenario:

```
$args2 = array('post_type' => 'custom',
               'tax_query' => array( 
                                array( 'taxonomy' => 'events', 
                                        'field' => 'slug',
                                        'terms' => array( 'tag1', 'tag-2')
                                      )
                                    )
                );
$query = new WP_Query($args);
echo $query->post_count;
```

You can see the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) for better understanding.

Comment: after adding 'operator' => AND   under terms i got exactly what i wanted. Big Thanks